# Can I cancel the CATransaction completionBlock?

Tags: ios, core-animation, catransaction

In a CATransaction I have the following code:

```
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    ...do something ....
}];
```

The animation runs for about half a second. I want to be able to cancel the completion block if some other events happen in the class logic...

Is there a way to prevent this block to run after the animation has started?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem?

Comment: @JoshGafni No, I have changed my class logic to work around this.

Comment: Thanks anyway!  Seems like functionality Apple should add.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some logic that will check state of other events. Somthing like this:

```
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    if(some other events happen){
       return;
    }
}];
```